# gclient error when running on a POWER LE machine

Tags: powerpc, gclient

I'm trying to run gclient on a Red Hat 8.3 Power LE machine. When I type gclient I get the following error:

```
[E2022-12-07T10:16:47.767550-07:00 1015280 0 annotate.go:273] goroutine 1:
#0 infra/tools/vpython/pep425.go:293 - vpython.getPEP425CIPDTemplateForTag()
  reason: failed to infer CIPD platform for tag [python:"cp38" abi:"cp38" platform:"linux_ppc64le"]

#1 infra/tools/vpython/main.go:50 - vpython.glob..func1()
#2 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/cipd/cipd.go:281 - cipd.(*PackageLoader).expanderForTags()
  reason: failed to get CIPD template arguments

#3 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/cipd/cipd.go:68 - cipd.(*PackageLoader).Resolve()
#4 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/venv/config.go:207 - venv.(*Config).makeEnv()
  reason: failed to resolve packages

#5 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/venv/venv.go:169 - venv.With()
#6 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/run.go:60 - vpython.Run()
#7 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/application/application.go:324 - application.(*application).mainImpl()
#8 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/application/application.go:413 - application.(*Config).Main.func1()
#9 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/application/support.go:46 - application.run()
#10 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/application/application.go:412 - application.(*Config).Main()
#11 infra/tools/vpython/main.go:144 - vpython.mainImpl()
#12 infra/tools/vpython/main.go:158 - vpython.Main()
#13 vpython/main.go:10 - main.main()
#14 runtime/proc.go:255 - runtime.main()
#15 runtime/asm_ppc64x.s:856 - runtime.goexit()
```

Any Ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was running `pip3 install httplib2`